# Bounding the probability of one Binomial r.v. greater than another.

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X_1\sim Bin(k,p_1)$ and $X_2\sim Bin(k,p_2)$ be independent r.v. such that $p_1\neq p_2$, and w.l.o.g. let $p_1>p_2$. I wish to upper bound $\Pr(X_2 \geq X_1)$, i.e. finding as tight as possible $B=B(k,p_1,p_2)$ such that 
$$
\Pr(X_2 \geq  X_1)\leq  B.
$$
According to [Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) we have
$$
\Pr(X_2 \geq  X_1) = \sum_{i=0}^k\Pr(X_1=i)\Pr(X_2\geq i)=\sum_{i=0}^k{k \choose i}p_1^i(1-p_1)^{k-i}\Pr(X_2\geq i).
$$
Expending the cdf did not produce anything interesting, therefore I tried using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430692/binomial-distribution-upper-bound-and-lower-bound) bound on the cdf, but did not get anywhere.

Ideas?

---

Update: see my answer below.

Comment: why does the $k$ suddenly turn into an $m$ in the second $=$ ?

Comment: You could try to use Tschebyscheffs inequality for the expression $\Pr(X_2 \geq i)$.

Comment: Are you assuming independence?

Comment: @Joker123 Thank, it was a typo. I wrote an answer below using [Hoeffding's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) inequality, inspired by your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Joker123's comment above:

Define a series of i.i.d. r.v. $B_1,\dots,B_k$ such that
$$
B_i=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{w.p. }  (1-p_1)p_2\\
0 & \text{w.p. }  p_1p_2 + (1-p_1)(1-p_2)\\
-1 & \text{w.p. }  p_1(1-p_2)\\
\end{cases}.
$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
\Pr(X_2 \geq X_1)&=\Pr(X_2-X_1\geq 0)=\Pr\left(\sum_{i=1}^k B_i \geq 0   \right) \\
& = \Pr\left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k B_i - (p_2-p_1) \geq (p_1-p_2)   \right).
\end{align}
Notice that $\mathbb E(B_i)=p_2-p_1$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$, and that $B_i$ is bounded in the interval $[-1,1]$. Finally, using [Hoeffding's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) we obtain 
$$
\leq \exp\left( -\frac{2k^2(p_1-p_2)^2}{4k} \right).
$$

Comment: Do you really intend to have a $\frac{2k^2}{4k}$ term rather than $\frac{k}{2}$ or is there an typo?

Comment: @Henry In favor of those who are not familiar with Hoeffding's Inequality, I presented it as appears in here -
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality . If you think it confuses readers, I'll change it.

Comment: Very nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

You could get an approximation (at least for reasonable $k$ and probabilities not close to $0$ and $1$) with $$\Phi\left(\dfrac{k(p_2-p_1)+\frac12}{\sqrt{k (p_1(1-p_1)+p_2(1-p_2))}}\right)$$

As an example, with $k=10$, $p_1=0.4$ and $p_2=0.2$, you have $P(X_2 \ge X_1) \approx 0.2244$ while the approximation gives about $0.2266$

You be even more likely to exceed the true probability by changing the $\frac12$ in the approximation to $1$.  The example would then suggest $0.3085$

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Normal approximation is indeed valuable. I ended up using concentration inequalities, see my answer below.