# Lower bound on the probability for a Binomial random variable to be greater than another

Tags: probability, asymptotics, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $(p_k),(q_k) , k \in \mathbb{N}$ be two sequences $ \in [1/2-\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon]$ s.t. $p_k>q_k$. For $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $B_k(p_k)$ and $B_k(q_k)$ be two independent binomial random variables with parameters $(k,p_k)$ and $(k,q_k)$ respectively.

### What I would like

I am looking for a non-trivial lower bound on
$$ \mathbb{P}(B_k(p_k) > B_k(q_k)) + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{P}(B_k(p_k) = B_k(q_k)) $$
as a function of $(p_k-q_k)$.
By ``non-trivial'', I mean strictly greater than $1/2$ :)

You can see this as the probability to beat an opponent in a $k$-rounds coin toss game, when both coins are only close to perfectly balanced.

I only need this lower bound to hold asymptotically (i.e., for $k$ large enough), and specifically, I'm considering the case $(p_k-q_k) = o(1/k)$.

I am ready to assume that $(p_k-q_k) > 1/e^{k/2}$ (in case such assumption is useful...)

### What I have tried already

Hoeffding's bound gives (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673745/bounding-the-probability-of-one-binomial-r-v-greater-than-another/2675948)):
$$ \mathbb{P}( B_k(p_k) > B_k(q_k) ) > 1 - \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} k (p_k-q_k) \right), $$
which goes to $0$ in my case.

I've also tried to use the Berry-Esseen theorem, ending up with:
$$ \mathbb{P}( B_k(p) > B_k(q) ) > \Phi \left( \frac{\sqrt{k}(p_k-q_k)}{\sigma_k} \right) - \frac{C}{\sigma_k \sqrt{k}} , $$
where $\sigma_k = \sqrt{p_k(1-p_k) + q_k(1-q_k)}$ and $C = 0.4748$ for instance. Again, the RHS is too small for my purpose, when $(p_k-q_k)$ is very small.

Comment: Have you tried the exact calculation when $p_k-q_k \ll 1/k$? For example when $k=100,p_k=0.5001, q_k=0.5$ you get about $0.47746$ which is well below $\frac12$.  It is a question of balancing the advantage given by $p_k > q_k$ against the disadvantage that equality does not count as greater than.

Comment: Thank you, I had missed the fact that equality may actually matter... (I had discarded this for the reason that $k$ goes to $+\infty$ -- but it may have been a mistake). Let me think about it and update the post.

By the way, how did you come up with this value? I've tried to write a little script with an exact computation, but it's not numerically accurate enough

Comment: In R something like `pgt<-function(k,p1,p2) {pdouble<-function(x,y){dbinom(x,k,p1)*dbinom(y,k,p2)}; sum(outer(0:k,0:k,">")*outer(0:k,0:k,pdouble))};`  and then `pgt(100,0.501,0.5)` gives `0.4774632`.  You will run out of memory if $k$ is much more than $1000$ and there are better ways to code it